# How many documents are stored in specified collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am use cloud Firestore to store users data and my question is:
Is it possible to know how many documents are stored in specified collection. If possible write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in aggregation queries in Cloud Firestore. So to get the count of documents in a collection, you will indeed either have to retrieve all those documents (as Emocuc answered) **or** keep the count of the number of documents in the database somewhere.

With the second approach you update a counter in the database, any time you add or remove a document. This adds some work to the write operations, but after to show the number of documents you simply can read the counter (instead of reading all documents). This kind of trade-off (more complex writes for a faster/simpler read) is *very* common in NoSQL database and is one of the reasons they can scale to so many readers.

The [Cloud Firestore documentation has some examples of these sort of aggregation operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) that I recommend you check out. While the samples are more complex than what you need, they are well documented and should be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Firestore almost always return entire collection, including all its documents. Hence, you just count the retrieved data. The code would depend on the language/framework you use, but all methods are well described [@official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/), if you have managed to retrieve data, you should be able to just count its items. Let say you need a service for Angular2+ using AngularFire2 and you like to use valueChanges() method. Once you map the retrieved data, you count its items. The code might look like this (ideally, you should add collection/document interfaces as well ):

```
import { Injectable       } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

constructor( private _fireStore: AngularFirestore ) { }

getSomething = () => {
  const collection_reference = this._fireStore.collection('logs');
  const collection_data = collection_reference.valueChanges();
  collection_data.map( data => {
      const number_of_documents = data.length;
    } ).subscribe((query) => {});
  }
}
```